# Property cobertura is not allowed - gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab-ci, cobertura

In our gitlab-ci.yml file, we have include reports in our testing stage from cobertura.

The yml worked fine up until a few days ago, and although literally nothing has been changed on the yml file, it is now being rejected as invalid.

The error is `Property cobertura is not allowed`.
[image: screenshot of our artifacts for the invalid job]

Since nothing has changed in our code, i'm wondering if there is an update on gitlab maybe or if there is a setting i need to change that someone may have altered by accident.

Not sure if it's helpful, but here is the error on gitlab..
[image: screenshot of gitlab error]

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As it was mentioned, the `artifacts:report:cobertura` has been deprecated. You can replace the

```
cobertura: backend/coverage/cobertura-coverage.xml
```

with the following:

```
coverage_report:
    coverage_format: cobertura
    path: backend/coverage/cobertura-coverage.xml
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're on GitLab 15.0, `artifacts:report:cobertura` has been deprecated and replaced by `artifacts:reports:coverage_report`.

Reference: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/deprecations.html#artifactsreportcobertura-keyword